# Is this a new syntax of C++11 initalizer?

Tags: c++

```
MySQLRouter::MySQLRouter(const int argc, char **argv)
: MySQLRouter(Path(argv[0]).dirname(),
              vector<string>({argv + 1, argv + argc}))
{
}
```

what's the  "vector({argv + 1, argv + argc})" mean ?

P.S. sorry for this simple question. I really don't know the syntax name, so I cannot google for it.

Comment: The term for this is an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (or if you're fancy, a braced-init-list). Also, I don't think that code does what the person who wrote it thinks it does.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't know what the person who wrote that code thinks that it does, but I think it constructs and passes a std::vector of std::strings, using the argv array for values. And I think that syntactically, that vector is constructed using copy construction from another temporary vector which is constructed using a two-argument constructor, but in the end copy elision elides the copy. Am I wrong? (Other than the detail that copy elision is optional.) Of course, the parentheses should be ditched to make the meaning clearer. But isn't the end result the same, in this case?

Comment: @NicolBolas Really help! thanks!  I really don't know this syntax, and don't know the name "list init" so I cannot google it , because I must know the syntax name first. So I have to write a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<string>({argv + 1, argv + argc})
```

constructs a `vector<string>` from the arguments `{argv + 1, argv + argc}` and uses that to construct a second `vector<string>` using the move constructor. The second object is passed to a second constructor of `MySQLRouter`.

You could also use a simpler form:

```
vector<string>{argv + 1, argv + argc}
```

or

```
vector<string>(argv + 1, argv + argc)
```

which will construct only one temporary object.

Having said that, using

```
vector<string>({argv + 1, argv + argc})
```

will not cause any performance penalties due to the use of the move constructor.

Here's simple test program that demonstrates the behavior explained above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void test(std::vector<std::string> const& v)
{
   for ( auto const& item : v )
   {
      std::cout << item << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   test(std::vector<std::string>({argv+1, argv+argc}));
   test(std::vector<std::string>(argv+1, argv+argc));
   test(std::vector<std::string>{argv+1, argv+argc});
}
```

When the program is run with:

```
./socc aa bb cc
```

I get the following output:

```
aa
bb
cc

aa
bb
cc

aa
bb
cc
```